# set_index on dict in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary such as

```
ds = [{'serving': 'hot', 'meal': 'breakfast', 'name': 'toasts'},
      {'serving': 'cold', 'meal': 'dinner', 'name': 'salad'},
      {'serving': 'cold', 'meal': 'lunch', 'name': 'salad'},
      {'serving': 'cold', 'meal': 'lunch', 'name': 'ice-cream'},
      {'serving': 'hot', 'meal': 'dinner', 'name': 'fondue'},]
```

And I would like to `set_index` in the same way I would do in Pandas. Eventually I would like to get:

```
>>> hierarchize(ds, ('serving', 'meal'), array=False, default=dict)
{'cold': {
    'dinner': [{'name': 'salad'}],
    'lunch':  [{'name': 'salad'},
               {'name': 'ice-cream'}]},
 'hot': {
    'breakfast': [{'name': 'toasts'}],
    'dinner': [{'name': 'fondue'}]}
}
```

So I wrote this and I am wondering if there is a more elegant way to do it using a builtin module.

```
def hierarchize(data, primary_keys, array=False, default=dict):
    import copy
    root = default()
    for entry in data:
        new_entry = copy.copy(entry)
        node = root
        for key in primary_keys:
            value = entry[key]
            element = [] if key == primary_keys[-1] else default()
            node[value] = node.get(value, element)
            parent = node
            node = node[value]
            new_entry.pop(key)
        if array:
            node.append(new_entry)
        elif key in node:
            raise ValueError('Duplicate key %s found in dataset' % key)
        else:
            parent[value] = new_entry
    return default(root)
```

Comment: This isn't a dictionary, this is a list of dictionaries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of a builtin module making the code more elegant, but how about a recursive approach?

```
def hierarchize(data, primary_keys):
    shorten = lambda d, pk: dict([(k, v) for k, v in d.items() if k != pk])
    if not primary_keys:
        return data
    res = {}
    for x in data:
        cat = x[primary_keys[0]]
        x_short = shorten(x, primary_keys[0])
        res[cat] = res[cat] + [x_short] if cat in res else [x_short]
    return dict([(k, hierarchize(v, primary_keys[1:])) for k, v in res.items()])
```

**Edit:**

`itertools.groupby()` can be leveraged to do what you want to some extent, so you may want to try this version:

```
from itertools import groupby

def hierarchize(data, primary_keys):
    get_key = lambda s: s[primary_keys[0]]
    shorten = lambda d, pk: dict([(k, v) for k, v in d.items() if k != pk])
    pk = primary_keys
    if not pk:
        return data
    return dict((k, hierarchize2([shorten(x, pk[0]) for x in v], pk[1:]))
                for k,v in groupby(sorted(data, key=get_key), get_key))
```

Comment: Good, but the latter version doesn't return the same as the former. Plus, both alter the initial `data`.

Comment: Fixed: The latter version had a bug, the `data` list needs to be sorted before grouping it. Also changed the former version so that the original data is unmodified.

Comment: So much shorter than my initial implementation. Thanks